# Protractor: how to make the configuration file more flexible?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, configuration-files

I have an idea to make my configs more flexible. For example I have 10000 config files with same parameters:

```
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
specs: ['C:/Users/Lilia.Sapurina/Desktop/Protractor Tests/Scenarios/ps-grid-column-filter-range_spec.js'],
params: {'url_filter': 'http://wks-15103:8010/ps/ng-components/examples/ps-grid-column-filter-range.html'}
```

And once I want to change path to specs, html or change selenium address. Can I do this in another file for all my configs?

For example write in my config:

```
seleniumAddress: '../Variables/seleniumAdress.txt'
```

Or maybe exist another interesting ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can export your common config rules as node.js module:

```
// globalProtractor.conf.js    
module.exports = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['C:/Users/Lilia.Sapurina/Desktop/Protractor Tests/Scenarios/ps-grid-column-filter-range_spec.js'],
  params: {
    'url_filter': 'http://wks-15103:8010/ps/ng-components/examples/ps-grid-column-filter-range.html'
}
```

And use in another file

```
// protractor.conf.js
var globalConf = require('/path/to/globalProtractor.conf.js');

globalConf.specs.push('path/new.spec.js');
exports.config = globalConf;
```

Comment: Can you override the onprepare function?

Answer (score 1):

With @driver_by help I found nice solution for my problem. Now my files isolated. If I want to change url or path to folder I should change only global config.

```
// globalProtractor.conf.js    
module.exports = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  baseUrl: 'http://wks-15103:8010/ps/ng-components/examples/',

  specs: [],

  path_to_scenario: '../Scenarios/',
  path_to_spec: '../Specs/',
  path_to_lib: '../Lib/'
}
```

And another file:

```
// protractor.conf.js
var globalConf = require('../Global_configs/globalProtractor_conf.js');        
    globalConf.specs.push(path_to_spec + 'ps-grid-column-filter-range_spec.js');    

globalConf.params = {'url_filter': 'ps-grid-column-filter-range.html',                          
                     'column_number_filter': 5,                                                 
                     'req_lib_filter': globalConf.path_to_lib + 'jasmine-expect'}               
exports.config = globalConf;
```